# android development google play service location API

Tags: android

I want to build an app that bring me my location using google play service. **I have done everything that needed** but it doesnt work  I think because of mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
that returns null and I dont know why. my project support google play service.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Location mLastLocation;
private TextView mLatitudeText;
private TextView mLongitudeText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLatitudeText);
    mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLongitudeText);
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        handleNewLocation(mLastLocation);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
```

}

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tazazo.locationgoogleplayservice"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tazazo.locationgoogleplayservice">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The "last location" can be `null` as in "unknown". Works as specified. You just need to handle that in your own code.

Comment: I handle it in onConnected function but still it not working. te app give me a message "LocationGooglePlayService has stopped"

Comment: Then there's some other reason for the crash and you should check out the crash log or add it to your question, if you do not understand it and want others to have a look. Also - although it should impossible - I've sometimes had a null `Location` object in `onLocationChanged()`, so it's not a bad idea to have a null check there too.